# Is C++ and .NET used together in Domains like Banking , Health Care and Telecom

Tags: c#, c++, programming-languages, architecture

This may seem relevant but it has some significance for me,may be few others like me.

I just want to know ,How Important is it to Learn C++ , COM and ATL while you are a .NET programmer?

I love programming with .NET and C# .Visual Studio just has it's own charm of intellisence ,Color Coding and other pretty features , which make us addicted to it.

I was thinking , almost we can build anything with C# and still it holds true mostly, but it lags sometimes like:

- While I try to create a Shell Extension , then it is highly suggested to use unmanaged code instead of any managed code.
- Also there are few other things like COM , ATL , which are preferred to be coded in C++ rather than C#.

I am just 4 years in IT industry and love to be Solution Architect.

So need all your inputs to know , how important/helpful will it be in my future venture if I am doing my Current COM Project with C++ ,  which integrate with .NET UI.

Is there any implementation of C++ and .NET in common domains like Health Care, Banking and Telecommunication.

Comment: I think this must be community wiki.

Comment: @Incognito: why? At least come up with a reason. There is nothing CW about this question. At worst you might want to vote to close it for being too vague or subjective, but I don't see why it should be CW. And even if you can dig up some obscure precedence (which should be possible because about 20% of SO users think *every* question not asked by them should be CW), I don't see how either the OP or the rest of SO gain anything from it being CW'ed.

Comment: @jalf Personally I don't see any reason for the question to be closed. Even more, I have voted for the question. But the questions like "I just want to know ,How Important is it to Learn C++ , COM and ATL while you are a .NET programmer?" as for me must be CW.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is C++ and .NET used together in Domains like Banking , Health Care and Telecom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395413/is-c-and-net-used-together-in-domains-like-banking-health-care-and-telecom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learnt plain old C 25 years ago and C++ 13 years ago and used each daily (until something better came along).  Since I started working with C# and .Net about 6-7 years ago I have had to use my previous C++ skills exactly **once**... (and I Googled the specific answer on that occasion anyway!).

Unless you intend to specialise in an area that requires those older skills, I have always found it better to learn/work with the most productive tools and languages (currently C#/.Net/WPF/Silverlight for me). If you do take the plunge into C++ & COM, ATL etc assume it will take years for you to become an expert in them.

Last year I was required to update an old DOS-based 1985 dBase II accounting system, as I happened to know DOS & dBase from 25 years ago, but it is unlikely those older skills will get used again either :)

Just my 2 cents worth. Hope it helps.