# Is C++ and .NET used together in Domains like Banking , Health Care and Telecom

Tags: c#, c++, windows, programming-languages, architecture

Or I should ask how helpful and benifitial will it be to start with C++

This may seem irelevant but it has some significance for me,may be few others like me.

I just want to know ,How Important is it to Learn C++ , COM and ATL while you are a .NET programmer?

I love programming with .NET and C# .Visual Studio just has it's own charm of intellisence ,Color Coding and other pretty features , which make us addicted to it.

I was thinking , almost we can build anything with C# and still it holds true mostly, but it lags sometimes like:

While I try to create a Shell Extension , then it is highly suggested to use unmanaged code instead of any managed code.
Also there are few other things like COM , ATL , which are preferred to be coded in C++ rather than C#.
I am just 4 years in IT industry and love to be Solution Architect.

So need all your inputs to know , how important/helpful will it be in my future venture if I am doing my Current COM Project with C++ , which integrate with .NET UI.

Is there any implementation of C++ and .NET in common domains like Health Care, Banking and Telecommunication.

Comment: I'm going to get blasted for this, but I think it would be fair to say that, by and large, C++ COM and ATL are not generally being used for new *business applications*, for a number of reasons.

Comment: I probably lean towards agreeing with Robert Harvey (and therefore concluding that it's not necessary for a .NET developer to learn C++, COM, and ATL), but for what it's worth, Visual Studio, with all of its Intellisense and color coding goodness, works with C++ as well.

Comment: @Cody: Well, intellisense in VS2008 and earlier (which you're forced into using if you need to target Win2k like myself) is pretty well broken for C++ projects of any reasonable size.

Comment: @James: I read that comment, and I think I died a little inside.

Comment: @Billy:  :-D  As for the Win2k issue, you can target the VC9 toolchain from Visual Studio 2010, so you can take advantage of the newer IDE and tools while still targeting the older compiler.  It's quite a handy feature.

Comment: @James: Yes, that's what I end up doing. I really really want to play with C++0x features and I can't though using vc9. *Bill cries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue (at least for the specific cases you mention, such as shell extensions) with trying to "integrate with a .NET UI" is that you really can't. The reason it's not a good idea to write shell extensions in managed code is that a given process can only load one version of the CLR at any given time. If two shell extensions depend on different versions of the CLR, and they both try to load at the same time, it will fail. You can't load the CLR in any way shape or form in the context of your shell extension and be a well behaved shell extension.

My advice would be to not bother with C++ until you really have a reason to learn it (despite that C++ is my favorite language). But when you do learn C++, *leave your .NET baggage at the door*. There are lots of things (such as excessive use of casting, constantly using `new`, etc) which are idiomatic C#, and are just plain **wrong** in C++. You will be a lot happier if you don't try to understand C++ concepts in terms of the CLR -- simply because C++ doesn't run there. You can use some of the design patterns you may have learned for C#, but how the underlying language and machine operates are completely different between the two languages.

Probably the most confusing difference for new C or C++ programmers is the concept of undefined behavior. The C and C++ standards are written in such a mannar as to not be tied to a particular machine. This is in stark contrast to architectures like Java or .NET, where the language is actually defined in terms of a virtual machine (and therefore is extremely dependent on that VM). This leads to places where the standard literally does not say what the correct output of a program should be; and instead says "however the underlying machine usually does this". You'll probably notice this quite a bit if you're ever dealing with floating point math. While C# has strict and specific rules about how and where floating points are calculated and rounded, C and C++ make no such qualifications.

Once you understand C++, then you can move on to COM and ATL. COM is essentially designed to make a C++ like class structure accessible in a language (the COM ABI), machine (marshalling between 32 bit and 64 processes on the same system, etc), and location (DCOM provides RPC facilities) independent way. If you don't understand the C++ object model, then you're going to have an extremely difficult time with the COM object model, because the two are extremely similar. ATL is a set of C++ class templates around COM fundamentals which simply handle some of the boilerplate for you.

Comment: +1 This is all excellent advice. My only quibble is that "excessive use of casting" is probably wrong in C#, too. Not only because doing anything in excess is bad, but because most of that casting presumably involves boxing and unboxing operations, which take time. And I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that it's possible to write fast code (like business applications, not necessarily shell extensions) in C# if you are knowledgeable about and mindful of the language and runtime.

Comment: @Cody: Thank you. Yes, I agree. Choosing a language merely because of speed is really a bad idea most of the time. Sure, are there specific cases where a language is the right choice because of speed (i.e. if you're developing the next **Unreal** engine), but those are *exceedingly* rare and aren't going to be the case for anything businessy.

Comment: Prior to .NET Framework 4.0, the CLR
allowed only one instance of itself to reside within a Windows process. For example, Microsoft Office Outlook couldn’t load
two add-ins that were built and tested against different versions of the .NET Framework.
However, with .NET Framework 4.0, Microsoft now supports the ability to load v2.0 and v4.0 in
a single Windows process. Ref: http://www.amazon.com/CLR-Via-C-Pro-Developer/dp/0735621632

Comment: @Jani: That's because the v4 framework can run v2 assemblies, not because multiple versions of the CLR can be loaded at once. If the v2 extension loads first then the v4 extension will still fail to load.

Comment: @Billy So you can solve this problem by reversing order of loading CLR versions. Just load V4.0 First then load the previous versions.

Comment: @Jani: Sure. All you have to do is decomple, hack/modify the shell, then disable NTFS permissions preventing you from replacing it, then replacing the shell, then rebooting the machine.... then having to deal when it breaks every other Windows Update. I'll stick with modifying the programs that I control TYVM :)

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know ,How Important is
>   it to Learn C++ , COM and ATL while
>   you are a .NET programmer?

Depends what you do. You are way better of learnin about databases. Pretty much every serious app uses a database.

But C++ IS ued together with .NET - especially C++/CLI (the managed variant) as it is very good for integrating C++ code with managed code effficiently. Quite often pretty much the only efficient way. Which is important if you for example raise events for market data. With a frequency in excess of 100.000 times. Per second.

But this is a NICHE. I work in the financial area, and tthe C++ uses AND integration uses are SMALL compared to the people working in .NET / In the application.

Comment: `C++/CLI` is more like C# than C++ though. It's essentially C# with some features cut off and a C++-like syntax. I therefore find it hard to consider that C++. Oh, and I've written plenty of "serious" and "businessy" applications which don't use some form of database. And so have other people.. i.e. every program in the Microsoft Office suite (except Access of course :P )